# Symfony2 custom console command appears as "not defined" upon execution

Tags: symfony, command

I created a new Class in src/CollaboratorsBundle/Command, named it GenerateFormRemindersCommand.php and put the following code in it:

```
<?php
namespace Myproject\CollaboratorsBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;

class GenerateFormRemindersCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand{

    protected function configure() {
        $this->setName("generate:formReminders")
             ->setDescription('Send reminders by email to all collaborators with unanswered forms');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        //some code
    }
}
```

Upon execution, i get the following message :

```
$ php app/console generate:formReminders
[InvalidArgumentException]
Command "generate:formReminders" is not defined.
```

I've checked in my AppKernel.php file that my bundle was registered in it and it was.

I've tried adding parent:configure(); to the configure method but without any results.

I've created a few other custom commands that work correctly. I don't get what I am doing wrong in this case. Do you ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 75):

I had the same trouble because I named file without "Command" suffix.
You have to name your file as 'GenerateFormRemindersCommand.php'.

Comment: You have no idea how right this answer is. Sheesh. Just ended half an hour of frustration for me.

Comment: @Jarrod, yeah, also spent about an hour. And I still don't understand why this 'Command' suffix is required even though there is a special namespace for all commands.

Comment: here is a reference from the symfony website saying exactly this:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html#automatically-registering-commands

Comment: After hours of frustration I finally stumbled upon this answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error. The problem I had was I implemented the constructor to initialize a repository field instead of the `initialize()` method.

Comment: that indeed solved my situation. Could you please explain why this behaves this way?

Answer (score 4):

If you configure your command as a service (for dependency injection or other purposes) and the command has a custom constructor - you shouldn't forget to tag it with `console.command`, e.g.

```
 your_service:
    class: Your\Class
    tags:
        - "console.command"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not placed your file at the correct location.

Looking over your code and the namespace used as well as you have already mentioned, that you have placed the file inside src/CollaboratorsBundle/Command. While it must be placed inside src/Myproject/CollaboratorsBundle/Command.

Answer (score 1):

execute

```
bin/console cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem but because I forgot to `extends ContainerAwareCommand`